# Modifying a collection in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection that looks like below using Coffeescript.

> ```
> class ListCollection extends Backbone.Collection
>     model: List
>     localStorage:
>         new Backbone.LocalStorage("TodoList")
> ```

I want to be able to change the "model" or "localStorage" property of an instance of ListCollection dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: You can modify the prototype probably and get around it, or just in the constructor dynamically check

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly simple:

```
class newClass extends ListCollection
    model: somethingElse
```

The only thing I'm not sure is the coffeescript class. But using `var NewModel = SomeModel.extend()` by passing an option object will overwrite the functions/attributes defined on the parent (basically it change/extends the prototype of `NewModel`).

Checkout the docs here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend (This work with every Backbone object: model, views, collection, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a collection with different kind of models (instead of different collections with specific model). Maybe this will suit you more:

```
class ListCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: (attrs, options) ->
       switch attrs.type
          when "car"
              new Car(attrs, options)
           else
              new Bus(attrs, options)
    localStorage:
        new Backbone.LocalStorage("TodoList")
```

If you add an object to the collection, it will look for it's type property. It will then go through a switch to determine it's type. This way a single collection could have different kind of models (and different parsers, validations, urls, etc)